# Android: Reading UTF8 csv file line by line does not stop on LF

Tags: java, android

I have the following code to read a UTF8 csv file line by line on Android:

```
InputStream fs = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
try(BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs, "utf8"))) {
   String line;
   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      emitStreamEvent(streamId, "data", line);
      if (tick > 0)
         SystemClock.sleep(tick);
   }
} catch (IOException e) { throw e;}
```

For an obscure reason, the string that is returned contains multiple lines.

When I copy the file over to my Mac and open it, it is processed correctly by Excel or TextEdit.

Here is the file from the perspective of VS Code:

[image]

The encoding and line ending:

[image]

Obviously I'm missing something but can't figure out what it is.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: The problem was on my side in code not shown here, not with readLine().

Comment: Why not explaining 'deadline' in the post?

Comment: My mistake there is no such thing as a 'deadline'.

Comment: Please provide your evidence. I've been using `BufferedReader.readLine()` for 22 years and never seen it.

Comment: @user207421 Added screen copies of the file. Will add an Android Studio Debugging output soon.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. I amu unable to see what the blue picture has to do with the black picture, or where either of them came from. Or how they relate to each other.

Comment: Well I thought that I've explained the pictures. Anyway, this process made me see the bug in my code. This has nothing to do with readLine(). Will close the question.

Comment: You explained nothing. You posted two screenshots that lacked any of the information I specified.

Comment: That is enough. I won't tolerate this kind of tone.